# Delete special characters and blank characters

Tags: laravel, tags, special-characters

I use laravel and search for a possibility in the tags to clear all special characters and blank characters before saving and that no empty tags are stored, if only special characters are entered. How can I do that?

```
if($product)
        {
            $tagNames = explode(',' ,$request->get('itag'));
            $tagIds = [];
            $toReplace = ['%', ' ', '_', '?', '&', '#', '$', '!', '"', '/', '(', ')', '=', '{', '}', '[', ']'];
            foreach($tagNames as $tagName)
            {
                $tag = Tag::firstOrCreate(['name' => str_replace($toReplace, '', $tagName)]);

                if ($tag) {
                    $tagIds[] = $tag->id;
                }
            }
            $interest->tags()->sync($tagIds);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code, you can use `str_replace` function for it like this

```
$toReplace = ['%', ' ', '_', '?', '&'];
foreach($tagNames as $tagName)
{
    if(!empty(str_replace($toReplace, '', $tagName))){
        $tag = Tag::firstOrCreate(['name'=>str_replace($toReplace, '-', $tagName)]);
       if($tag)
       {
          $tagIds[] = $tag->id;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, it works. But I replace with '' without content. The problem is that it will clean the empty tags if only special characters are entered. How can I delete a completely empty tag automatically at this point?

Comment: thanks, unfortunately something is wrong with your code. I get an error message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Comment: Ohh, sorry ! Error fixed !

Comment: sorry i still have the same problem. If I enter a tag with %%%, an empty tag will be saved. Is it possible that the empty tags are not saved?